# remove all numbers after space in a dataset

Tags: oracle

I have been learning regexp_replace to clean up my dataset and have come across a new problem.

I have a dataset that looks like this:

$14..89
30 0
40 -
56 e
37.5
0.25
16.8.9

I want the data set to look like this:
14.89
30
40
56
37.5
0.25
16.89

I have used the following codes:

```
SELECT CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE('30 0', '(\.)\.+|[^0-9.]', '\1\2\3') AS DECIMAL(16,2)) from dual;
```

the problem with the first code is, although it works on the other numbers, it turns 30 0 into 300, when it should be 30

```
SELECT CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE('.25', '(\.)\.+|[^0-9]|(\w+).*$', '\1\2\3') AS DECIMAL(16,2)) from dual;

SELECT CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE('.25 0', '(\.)\.+|[^0-9]|(^.*?)(\w+).*$', '\1\2\3') AS DECIMAL(16,2)) from dual;
```

the problem with the two codes at the top is, even though it turns 30 0 into 30 (which is what I want), it messes up the other numbers.

If someone could help me solve this issue so that I can get all the numbers to look the way it is in the second list, that would be great. Thank you

Comment: Looks like your objective is to convert the dataset into valid numerics, correct? What other anomalies have you come across so far besides (1) Inclusion of symbol (2) Space after number (3) An extra period (.)?

Comment: @taylorswiftfan that's correct (also love your name).  These 3 are the anomalies that exist in the dataset so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('30 0', ' .*$'),'(\.)\.+|[^0-9.]', '\1\2\3') FROM dual
```